# CustomEvent with response, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to incorporate a CustomEvent in my workflow.
But I need this event to be a communication in both ways: a script sends the event to the document, and it should respond to the same initiator.

I've tried stuff along the lines of:

```
ev = new CustomEvent('StorageRequest', {
  detail: {
    space: theSpace,
    method: theMethod,
    arguments: args
  }
})
document.dispatchEvent(ev)
```

And my listener looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('StorageRequest', (e) => {
  console.debug('Sending StorageRequest', e)
  // do something, then answer back with response
})
```

What's the way to achieve this?

I've tried using a Promise and sending the response using resolve/reject, but passing functions seems to break the `detail` in the event and it turns out to be null if I try to do that:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ev = new CustomEvent('StorageRequest', {
    detail: {
      space: theSpace,
      method: theMethod,
      arguments: args,
      resolve, reject
    }
  })
  document.dispatchEvent(ev)
})
```

> **Notes:** 
>   I'd like to avoid "generically" sending the response back to the document. I prefer the requests and responses to be fully intentional and handled within the code properly
>   I don't have an element attached to this, so using the element from `e.target` isn't an option (unless I can do something else with it)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "respond" in a DOM Event - they just propagate up the DOM tree until it reaches the top level.

A promise may work, setup correctly, but you would only be able to respond once. Once the promise is resolved/rejected you cannot resolve or reject it again, it will ignore subsequent resolve/reject calls.

As an alternative you can setup 2 separate events and respond to the first which should achieve what you are attempting to do:

```js
sReqEvent = new CustomEvent('StorageRequest', {
    detail: {
    space: theSpace,
    method: theMethod,
    arguments: args
});

console.debug('Sending StorageRequest');
document.dispatchEvent(sReqEvent);
```

Listeners:

```
document.addEventListener('StorageRequest', (e) => {
    // do something, then answer back with response
    var sRespEvent = new CustomEvent('StorageResponse', e.data);
    console.debug('Sending StorageResponse', e.data);
    document.dispatchEvent(sRespEvent);
});

document.addEventListener('StorageResponse', (e) => {
    // This is my response
});
```

Granted this is unnecessary and you could just use a "StorageResponse" function that is called from within the StorageRequest listener...

---

Another alternative is to use `window.postMessage`, but that is more involved to setup with separate back/forth requests and IE9 will only support strings being passed (you need to JSON encode/decode the package in IE9 if you want to send anything other than a string - works, but is slower if you do it in all browsers as a global workaround).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I've considered having this `StorageResponse` pattern, but I wasn't sure how to handle multiple instances - do you have an idea how to make sure the right response goes to the right response callback? (Assuming they just need to return the promises to their correct chains)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "right response" - having multiple concurrent calls? If that is the case you would need to pass some form of ID in the data (the second parameter passed to `new CustomEvent('StorageRequest', ... )`) and check that ID in the `StorageResponse` listener.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with using a `CustomEvent` for request/response communications with a storage service and found that the event listener could modify the detail value, and it could be read be the event dispatcher.  I tested with up-to-date (Feb 2023) versions of Chrome, FireFox, and Edge, it does seems to work; however, I don't know if this will continue to work in the future.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="DataStoreService.js" type="module" defer></script>
    <script src="app-test.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**DataStoreService.js**

```
export class DataStoreService {
  static store = new Map();

  static initialize = () => {
    document.addEventListener('datastore-service', (ev) => {
      const request = ev.detail.request;
      const response = {};
      switch (ev.detail.operation) {
        case 'insert':
          DataStoreService.store.set(request.key, request.value);
          break;
        case 'get':
          response.value = DataStoreService.store.get(request.key);
          break;
        case 'remove':
          DataStoreService.store.delete(request.key);
          break;
        case 'keys':
          response.keys = [...DataStoreService.store.keys()];
          break;
      }
      ev.detail.response = response;
    });
  };
}

DataStoreService.initialize();
```

**app-test.js**

```
const datastore = (operation, request) => {
  const event = new CustomEvent('datastore-service', {
    detail: { operation, request },
    bubbles: true,
  });
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
  return event.detail.response;
};

console.log('insert key=8');
datastore('insert', {
  key: 8,
  value: { name: 'Monique', phone: '6045550967' },
});

console.log('insert key=9');
datastore('insert', {
  key: 9,
  value: { name: 'Larry', phone: '9025551245' },
});

const keys = datastore('keys').keys;
console.log('keys: ', keys);
keys.forEach((key) =>
  console.log(`get: key=${key}: `, datastore('get', { key }).value)
);

console.log('remove key=8');
datastore('remove', { key: 8 });

console.log('keys: ', datastore('keys').keys);
```

**console**

```
insert key=8
insert key=9
keys:  (2) [8, 9]
get: key=8:  {name: 'Monique', phone: '6045550967'}
get: key=9:  {name: 'Larry', phone: '9025551245'}
remove key=8
keys:  [9]
```

With promises is could work something like this:

```
const datastore = (operation, request) => {
  const event = new CustomEvent('datastore-service', {
    detail: { operation, request },
    bubbles: true,
  });
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
    resolve(event.detail.response);
  });
};

console.log('insert key=8');
datastore('insert', {
  key: 8,
  value: { name: 'Monique', phone: '6045550967' },
});

datastore('keys').then((keysResponse) =>
keysResponse.keys.forEach((key) =>
    datastore('get', { key }).then((response) =>
      console.log(`get: key=${key}: `, response.value)
    )
  )
);
```